# Model is not exported after running model_main_tf2.py and exporter_main_v2.py. Don't know why?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am doing object detection using TensorFlow Object Detection API in Google colab. This is my directory structure.

```
object_detection/
  training/
  exported_model/
  pipeline.config
  model_main_tf2.py
  exporter_main_v2.py
```

I run bellow for training.

```
!python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=training --pipeline_config_path=pipeline.config
```

I run bellow for exporting model.

> !python exporter_main_v2.py 
> --input_type image_tensor 
> --pipeline_config_path pipeline.config 
> --trained_checkpoint_dir training/ 
> --output_directory exported_model

None of the above will produce any error but after running both I am not able to see exported model in desired directory in my case(exported_model). I didn't understand what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that while I run training even though it didn't produce any error It also not successful. Because It didn't generate files which should be generated after successful training like checkpoints. The `training/`  directory was blank.

[this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/exporter_main_v2.py) file's documentation helped me to figure out my problem. You can check it for further guidance.

Comment: Can you please share what was the issue in your case ? 
I've been studying that py script for exporting but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

i follow the [struction](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tf2.md) using export_tflite_graph_tf2.py

Comment: the instruction you shared is for tensorflow lite. It does not applicable. I am following tensorflow object-detection api tutorial. https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#configuring-a-training-job

Comment: Please be careful with English quality when answering a question.